# jQuery input addition

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i want addition some inputs, radio buttons etc from fluent forms plugin in wordpress.

But im struggling with problem that i have 4 buttons each of them have different value, but in result still showed me number from first option. Please how i get right number from option on click?

i use this script

```
    jQuery(document).click(function() 
{
  var a = jQuery("input[name='typ_podorysu']").attr("data-calc_value");
  var d = a;
    jQuery("#result").text(d);
    console.log(d)
});
```

[image]

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified example based on your code.

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[name='typ_podorysu']").click(function() {
    var d = $(this).attr("data-calc_value");
    $("#result").append(d+"\n");
  });
});
```

```css
textarea{width:100%;height:200px;margin:20px 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="typ_podorysu" value="1" data-calc_value="1"> (value = 1, calc_value = 1)
  </div>  
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="typ_podorysu" value="2" data-calc_value="1"> (value = 2, calc_value = 1)
  </div>  
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="typ_podorysu" value="3" data-calc_value="2"> (value = 3, calc_value = 2)
  </div>  
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="typ_podorysu" value="4" data-calc_value="3"> (value = 4, calc_value = 3)
  </div>  
</div>

<div>
  <textarea id="result"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it works! But follow-up question how get value from another inputs with different name for example: name="typ-dveri" values can be same for example... and then addition these two variables please

Comment: `$("input[name='typ_podorysu'],input[name='typ-dveri']")`. Please up vote the answer if you find it helpful and if you think it is the best answer you can green-tick it.

Comment: but addition is not working as well... i just need to addition two numbers...but i tried what you suggest me but is not what i want https://jsfiddle.net/bendakfilip/wzufs0d4/#

Comment: Ok, now I got what you want to do, it wasn't very clear for me. I'll make you an example after a few minutes.

Comment: Here is the fiddle of what you want https://jsfiddle.net/f1cxv62r/1/

Comment: yes yes it works:) and last simple question for you if i want addition radio buttons and also numeric inputs and .change not work what i need to use to see realtime calculation...i mean if i increase number in input automatically increase result value https://jsfiddle.net/bendakfilip/wzufs0d4/14/#&togetherjs=U62050vA6t

Answer (score 0):

If you find that you need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) you can use this method:

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', "input[name='test']", (function() {
  var a = jQuery(this).attr("data-test");
  console.log(a);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
click me
<input type="radio" name="test" data-test="1">
<input type="radio" name="test" data-test="2">
<input type="radio" name="test" data-test="3">
```